# Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported. Ubuntu 16.04.5

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, kernel, dpkg

```
$ sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

---

```
~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
After this operation, 336 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 284481 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31~16.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-4.15.0-29 (4.15.0-29.31~16.04.1) ...
Removing linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31~16.04.1) ...
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31~16.04.1) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

What do I have to do to fix the error?

Comment: That's not an error, that's just a warning.  You can ignore it safely.

Comment: Will something happen if I restart the notebook? I have a Notebook dell inspiron 14-3467.
Excuse my ignorance, but I'm new to Linux and there are things that I find hard to understand.

Comment: GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details, especially when they contain some code. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing is just a warning.  This means that it's just indicating that the default configuration has an option set while another is set, and that it does nothing.

**There is no error here.**  You could ignore the warning from here until the end of time and it wouldn't matter.

It does not mean there's anything broken, it's just a warning message about some feature no longer being supported, but it will not break your system or cause problems.

Comment: Ok then I can quietly restart the notebook and nothing will happen?

Comment: @Padafa yes, you can reboot without issue.

Answer (score 2):

@ThomasWard is correct in saying that it is only a warning and can be ignored.  If you want to get rid of that warning, copy and paste the following to a terminal window:

```
sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0/#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0/' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

The warning should be gone from now on.

Comment: sudo sed -i 's/GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0/#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0/' /etc/default/grub
$ sudo update-grub2
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done

Comment: @Padafa You should be good now.  You can even reboot if you want.